# Error: Some NCCL operations have failed or timed out

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, distributed, nvidia-docker

While running a distributed training on 4 A6000 GPUs, I get the following error:

```
[E ProcessGroupNCCL.cpp:630] [Rank 3] Watchdog caught collective operation timeout: WorkNCCL(OpType=BROADCAST, Timeout(ms)=1800000) ran for 1803710 milliseconds before timing out.       
                                                                                                                                                        [E ProcessGroupNCCL.cpp:390] Some NCCL operations have failed or timed out. Due to the asynchronous nature of CUDA kernels, subsequent GPU operations might run on corrupted/incomplete data. To avoid this inconsistency, we are taking the entire process down.                                                                                 

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'                                                                                                        
what():  [Rank 2] Watchdog caught collective operation timeout: 
WorkNCCL(OpType=BROADCAST, Timeout(ms)=1800000) ran for 1804406 milliseconds before timing out.        

[E ProcessGroupNCCL.cpp:390] Some NCCL operations have failed or timed out. Due to the asynchronous nature of CUDA kernels, subsequent GPU operations might run on corrupted/incomplete data. To avoid this inconsistency, we are taking the entire process down.
```

I use standard NVidia PyTorch docker. Interesting thing is that training works fine for small datasets but for the bigger datasets, I get this error. So I can confirm that the training code is correct and does work.

There is no actual runtime error or any other information to get an actual error messages anywhere.

Answer (score 8):

Following two have solved the issue:

- Increase default SHM (shared memory) for CUDA to 10g (I think 1g would have worked as well). You can do this in docker run command by passing `--shm-size=10g`. I also pass `--ulimit memlock=-1`.
- `export NCCL_P2P_LEVEL=NVL`.

**Debugging Tips**

To check current SHM,

```
df -h
# see the row for shm
```

To see NCCL debug messages:

```
export NCCL_DEBUG=INFO
```

Run p2p bandwidth test for GPU to GPU communication link:

```
cd /usr/local/cuda/samples/1_Utilities/p2pBandwidthLatencyTest
sudo make
./p2pBandwidthLatencyTest
```

For A6000 4 GPU box this prints:

[image]

The matrix shows bandwith betweeb each pair of GPU and with P2P, it should be high.

Answer (score 7):

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html#torch.distributed.init_process_group

set timeout param in torch.distributed.init_process_group(), default is 30 mins

```
torch.distributed.init_process_group(backend, init_method=None, timeout=datetime.timedelta(seconds=1800), world_size=- 1, rank=- 1, store=None, group_name='', pg_options=None)
```

Answer (score 2):

When I set NCCL_DEBUG=INFO, the output said, "Could not enable P2P between dev 2(=d5000) and dev 1(=d1000) ...". So, I set the environment variable NCCL_P2P_DISABLE=1, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem turned out to be the `torchrun` command for PyTorch 1.10.1. I only needed to switch to the `python -m torch.distributed.launch` command and everything worked. I spent many hours on the StackOverflow and the PyTorch Forum but no one mentioned this solution, so I'm sharing it to save people time.

`torchrun` seems to be working fine for PyTorch 1.11 and above.